# Lexing and Parsing CSS hierarchy

Tags: parsing, f#

```
.someDiv { width:100%; height:100%; ... more properties ... }
```

How would I make up a rule in my parser that will match the string above?

Seems rather impossible for me, since you cant define an unlimited amount of properties in the rule? Could someone please clarify, how you would do such a thing with `FsLex` and `FsYacc`?

Comment: I don't understand where is the difficulty. If you need parsing examples, have a look at ocamlyacc tutorials. If the problem is the number of properties, put your properties in a dictionary; In fsyacc, match for any word before the colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using FsLex and FsYacc then you can parse the properties inside `{ ... }` as a list of properties. Assuming you have a lexer that properly recognizes all the special characters and you have a rule that parses individual property, you can write something like:

```
declaration:
  | navigators LCURLY propertyList RCURLY { Declaration($1, $3) }
  | navigators LCURLY RCURLY              { Declaration($1, []) }

propertyList:
  | property SEMICOLON propertyList    { $1::$2 }
  | property                           { [$1] }

property:
  | IDENTIFIER COLON values            { Property($1, $3) }
```

The `declaration` rule parses the entire declaration (you'll need to write parser for various navigators that can be used in CSS such as `div.foo #id` etc.) The `propertyList` rule parses one property and then calls itself recursively to parse multiple properties.

The values constructed on the right-hand-side are going to be a list of values representing individual property. The `property` rule parses individual property assignment e.g. `width:100%` (but you'll need to finish parsing of values, because that can be a list or a more compelx expression).

Comment: Couldn't this be refactored to http://www.pastie.org/2144473 ? Or does FsYacc actually associate a different meaning with | than the original yacc here?

Comment: @Zor sorry for delayed response, but the answers to your questions are yes and no. It should work just fine.