# FsLex - Differ between 2 strings

Tags: f#, lexical-analysis, fslex

I've a couple of tokens:

`PNAME` and `ENAME` - both are strings.

Now I want to setup 2 rules in my lexer, in order to match those tokens.

**The first rule** (`PNAME`) should match when the string consist of characters a-z, and optional special 
characters @/().

**The second rule** (`ENAME`) should match when the string consist of characters a-z, and an optional prefix (#/.).

Now how would I make up a rule in my lexer file that only would match `ENAME` - Even when theres no prefix?

If it makes any difference, then `ENAME` will have a `{` after it's string like: `(prefix)eName {` - However this bracket shouldn't be passed into the parser...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this question is related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532720/lexing-and-parsing-css-hierachy) (about parsing CSS) files, then you should probably use a different approach.

The lexer should only identify simple tokens such as `#` and `.` (token names `HASH` and `DOT`), curly braces (tokens `LCURLY` and `RCURLY` for `{` and `}` respectively) and any identifier `IDENT` using regular expression that takes any sequence of characters `a-zA-Z`.

The rest of the processing (such as identifying CSS rules `.foo { ... }`) should be done in the parser. In my previous answer, I described how to parse a list of property names - it assumes that you have `navigators` which is a syntactic element that specifies the HTML elements such as `#name` or `#name .class`. You can write separate parsing rules for these:

```
navigators = 
  | navigator            { [$1] }
  | navigator navigators { $1::$2 }
navigator = 
  | HASH IDENT   { SelectByID($2) }
  | DOT IDENT    { SelectByClass($1) }
```

For more information about wirting parsers & lexers see the [wikibooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lexing_and_Parsing) and [Chris Smith's blog](http://blog.achrissmith.com/2010/04/fslex-and-fsyacc-examples-updated.html).

Comment: Ah, it makes a lot more sense now. Thanks! (again) ^^